# Automate numbering equations for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Recently, I learned that I can manually number my equations in word by type `#(1)`  after the equation, e.g., `\alpha#(1)`, via this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/594559/how-do-you-easily-add-equation-numbers-to-microsoft-word-2010-equations/868682). Now I would like to create a VBA macro, so that it detects all equations in my active document which are in display mode, and number them automatically (either by using a field or something else). Currently, I'm still working through the code, but I'm stuck on getting the selected equation text and replace it with itself plus `#(i)`. Here is my code so far

```
Sub NumberDisplayedEquations()
  Dim objEq As OMath
  Dim objRange As Range
  With ActiveDocument
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim j As Integer
      j = 1
      For i = 1 To .OMaths.Count
          Set objEq = .OMaths(i)
          If objEq.Type = wdOMathDisplay Then
            objEq.Linearize
            Set objRange = objEq.Range
            objRange.Text = objRange.Text + "#(" + Format(j, (0)) + ")"

            Set objRange = .OMaths.Add(objRange)
            Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
            objEq.BuildUp
            j = j + 1
          End If
      Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Indeed, this works for simple equations. However, if I have anything more complicated, e.g., equations that are aligned via the equal sign, then my code breaks. I don't quite understand why, so it would be great if someone had any pointers.

**EDIT**. The problem seems to be that if I were to write down an equation in display mode, e.g., press `alt-=`, then type `\alpha =x+2`, press `shift+enter` instead of `enter`, and proceed to write the next line of equation, word adds an extra `newline` character at the end of `\alpha =x+2`. Indeed, using a `MsgBox` to return the text of the equation, there is an extra square-like character at the end of the original equation `\alpha =x+2`. I don't know how to go on and detect such a character, since I can't even type such a character.

**EDIT 2**. I realized that pressing `shift-enter` creates a manual line break, i.e., adds a character called `vbVerticalTab`, so I need to delete this character before I do number the equations. Indeed, I have copy-pasted my working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, here is a working vba macro code. The first numbers the equations, the second clears the numbering. The only caveat is that equations that were previously aligned are no longer aligned when numbered. I'm not sure how to deal with this yet.

```
Sub NumberDisplayedEquations()
  Dim objEq As OMath
  Dim objRange As Range
  With ActiveDocument
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim j As Integer
      j = 1
      For i = 1 To .OMaths.Count
          Set objEq = .OMaths(i)
          If objEq.Type = wdOMathDisplay Then
              objEq.Linearize
              Set objRange = objEq.Range
              If InStr(1, objRange.Text, vbVerticalTab) Then
                  objRange.Text = Replace(objRange.Text, vbVerticalTab, "") + "#(" + Format(j, (0)) + ")" + vbNewLine
              Else
                  objRange.Text = objRange.Text + "#(" + Format(j, (0)) + ")"
              End If
              Set objRange = .OMaths.Add(objRange)
              Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
              objEq.BuildUp
              j = j + 1
          End If
      Next i
  End With
End Sub

Sub ClearDisplayedEquationsNumber()
  Dim objEq As OMath
  Dim objRange As Range
  With ActiveDocument
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim j As Integer
      Dim L As Integer
      Dim R As Integer
      j = 1
      For i = 1 To .OMaths.Count
          Set objEq = .OMaths(i)
          If objEq.Type = wdOMathDisplay Then
              objEq.Linearize
              Set objRange = objEq.Range
              R = InStr(1, objRange.Text, "#(")
              If R > 0 Then
                  objRange.Text = Mid(objRange.Text, 3, R - 3)
                  Set objRange = .OMaths.Add(objRange)
                  Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
                  objEq.BuildUp
              End If
          End If
      Next i
  End With
End Sub
```